# Unable to subclass a control without System.NullReferenceException being thrown

Tags: xamarin.ios, interface-builder, xamarin, xib

I am trying to subclass `UILabel` in my MonoTouch iOS app, as I have been informed this is the most reliable method of applying a custom font. I have added the font to my `Resources` folder and added the entries to the `Info.plist` file, however I am getting consistent errors when running the application with the subclass specified in IB. Here's the code:

*OpenSansRegularLabel.cs*

```c#
[Register("OpenSansRegularLabel")]
public partial class OpenSansRegularLabel : CustomFontLabel
{
    public OpenSansRegularLabel() : base("OpenSans-Regular", 10f) {}
}
```

*CustomFontLabel.cs*

```csharp
public class CustomFontLabel : UILabel
{
    private readonly string _fontName;
    private readonly float _pointSize;

    public CustomFontLabel(string fontName, float pointSize)
    {
        _fontName = fontName;
        _pointSize = pointSize;
    }

    public override void AwakeFromNib() 
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib();
        Font = UIFont.FromName(_fontName, _pointSize);
    }
}
```

In my XIB file in XCode I have specified the custom class as `OpenSansRegularLabel` on my UILabel. As stated though this gives me an error in `AppDelegate.cs` every time:

```c#
UIWindow window;
UIViewController viewController;

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    viewController = new UserGuideMainScreen();
    window.RootViewController = viewController;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible(); // Error thrown here: System.NullReferenceException

    return true;
}
```

This seems like such a simple problem to solve, I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was my own mistake - I had not included all the required constructors for `UILabel`. Should it help anyone in the future, I'll include the final working code below:

*CustomFontLabel.cs*

```
public class CustomFontLabel : UILabel
{
    public string FontName { get; set; }

    public CustomFontLabel() {}
    public CustomFontLabel(IntPtr ptr) : base(ptr) { }
    public CustomFontLabel(NSCoder coder) : base(coder) { }

    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        Font = UIFont.FromName(FontName, Font.PointSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use Attributed strings to customize the font styling for the label. Then instead of using the Text property, just use the AttributedText property to set the text.

Here is an example:

```csharp
NSMutableAttributedString attrString;
NSRange range1;

using (attrString = new NSMutableAttributedString(String.Format ("{0}*", label.Text))) 
{
    range1 = new NSRange (0, attrString.Length);
    attrString.AddAttribute (UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, UIColor.FromRGB(199, 90, 49), range1);
    attrString.AddAttribute (UIStringAttributeKey.Font, UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue-Bold", 12f), range1);
    label.AttributedText = attrString;              
};
```